# ImportError: No module named xxx

Tags: python, py2exe

```
from lib import mod_a 
print mod_a.MyClassName 
Result:<class 'lib.mod_a.MyClassName'>

print __import__("mod_a").MyClassName
Result:<class 'mod_a.MyClassName'>
```

When run as **exe**(created by py2exe),raise an error

```
print mod_a.MyClassName
Result:<class 'lib.mod_a.MyClassName'>


#Error
print __import__("mod_a").MyClassName
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 28, in 
>   print **import**("mod_a").MyClassName
>   ImportError: No module named mod_a

---

This is my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup  
import py2exe
import sys

includes = ["encodings", "encodings.*"]
sys.argv.append("py2exe")
sys.argv.append("-p lxml,gzip")
options = {"py2exe": {
                  "compressed": 1,
                  "optimize": 2,
                  "ascii": 0,
                  "bundle_files": 1,
                  }
        }
setup(
        version = "",
        description = "",
        name = "",
        options = options,
        zipfile=None,
        console = [{"script":'test.py',
                    'icon_resources':[(1, 'update.ico')]}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print sys.modules["lib.mod_a"].MyClassName
```

Work well on exe!